# How do I tell Chrome's Translator to ignore certain elements?

Tags: google-chrome, translation

I want my users to be able to use Chrome's built in translator, but I don't want it to translate certain values such as usernames, email addresses, filenames, other nouns, etc.

Is there an attribute I can stick on elements that I do/don't want to be translated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've answered my own question after doing some digging around.

Chrome translate will ignore all elements with class 'notranslate'.

For example, given the following code:

```
<strong>Don't translate me</strong>
```

Adding this will force chrome to ignore it:

```
<strong class="notranslate">Don't translate me</strong>
```